# How to set up branch label in TeamCity?

Tags: .net, teamcity

Now I have this columns, but I want to add one more: branch name.

**What I have:**
[image]
**Expected:**
[image]
Is it possible?

I use: TeamCity Professional 2017.2.2 (build 50909)

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: no, second picture is what I want

Comment: add your Version Control Settings to the question body

Comment: I can't do that, but you could tell me what to change... to see that branch names

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a **Logical Branch Name** and can be achieved through the inclusion of a **branch specification**. TeamCity uses this to calculate the logical name to display, as well as enables your build configuration to work with a collection of branches (either specified explicitly by name, or using a wildcard pattern).

Under your VCS root settings, you will find a field for Branch Specifications. You could include something like:

```
+:refs/heads/feat/*
```

This will allow your build configuration consume any branches prefixed with "feat/" in their name. **When the build runs for one of the branches, it will include the name on the dashboard like you have in your second image.**

The default branch is included in the branch specification by default, but if you want to explicitly give it a logical branch name (ie. show that name on the dashboard), you can use the parentheses syntax:

> You do not need to include the default branch into the branch specification as it is already included there implicitly. But, if you want to have some short logical branch name for the default branch in the UI, e.g.  master, you can include it in the branch specification and use the parentheses:
>
> +:refs/heads/(master)

*Note: TeamCity will only include the portion after the branch spec in the label name.* For example, using the feat/* branch specification above, a branch of feat/my-new-branch would only show as "my-new-branch" on the dashboard. You can apply a logical branch name to work around this if you wish with parentheses.

You can find the full TeamCity Feature Branch documentation [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Working+with+Feature+Branches#WorkingwithFeatureBranches-Configuringbranches)